# Can't get div height when including javascript in Django template

Tags: jquery, django

I'm trying to use the flot plugin for jquery and it keeps on complaining that a div has a width/height of zero.  I'm actually including the javascript for this in a Django template.  So my template file looks like:

```
<style>
#graph {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
}
</style>
<script>
$.plot(stuff)
console.log($(#graph).width())
</script>
<div id="#graph">
</div>
```

This template code is inserted into the DOM of another page with AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'something',
     success: function(data){ $("#content").html(data);
              console.log($("#graph").width()) }
});
```

For some reason, I can't get the width to be non-zero, but if I test the width in the "success" function from the ajax call, it returns correctly.  Is something wrong with the order that commands are being run/placed into the DOM?

Comment: Are the required javascript library files being included when you view source on your page?   If so, this problem doesn't relate to Django at all, it's all on the clientside.

Comment: They're included in the file that calls the Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your first code block, you are checking the width of your DIV before you actually create the DIV in your markup, and sense you aren't using a DOMReady event or Window Loaded event, it will come up 0 or null at best.

So, if you just move your script block below the div in your first example that will fix that.

I imagine you will find a similar situation in your second example but I can't be sure without seeing more code.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left that out. I've tried sticking it in a $().ready(), but it still does the same thing.  The second example is actually the same thing, I'm just using js to load in that template info into another page.